# How can I mount a UTM shared directory (volume) in a Linux guest?

Tags: mount, virtualization

In UTM there is a notion of a shared directory. I can select any directory I want and it's shared with the guest operating system. How do I access that data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access the shared directory you'll have to make sure you kernel is built with `9pnet_virtio` you can use this command to confirm the module is there, `sudo modinfo 9pnet_virtio`

Then you can run

```bash
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio share /tmp/host_files
```

Or you can add this in fstab for persistance upon reboot.

```bash
share   /tmp/host_files 9p  trans=virtio,rw,nofail  0   0
```

---

Thanks to [a user in the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mmmmmm) for pointing out this is docuemnted in the [UTM docs](https://docs.getutm.app/guest-support/linux/#virtfs)

Comment: Thanks a ton man. I was banging my head because `mount` command wasn't showing the mounted files (maybe due to this virtio).

Comment: Does this work between reboots?

Comment: @mmmmmm no you'd have to update your fstab. And if you find the command that works please [edit] this with that info. If not maybe I'll get around to it soon. I just got another Apple Silicon mac so this is again going to be an issue for me soon (and I'll update this soon).

Comment: The UTM document https://docs.getutm.app/guest-support/linux/#macos-virtiofs gives a simpler mount command. It also mention the fstab

Comment: @mmmmmm cool cool, updated.